# How return a value with the input function?

Tags: python, input, return, user-input

Hi guys I'm new to python. I've been trying to return a value with an input function to the return can anyone help me out?

```
def bike_wash(amount):
    print("Welcome to your bike wash")
    print("Please enter your desired wash")
    
    if (amount == 100):
        print("Thanks for choosing basic wash")
        print("Enjoy water wash with spray")

    if (amount == 200):
        print("Thanks for choosing Premium wash")
        print("Enjoy foam wash to the entire body")


amount = input()
bike_wash(amount)
```

Comment: What’s the issue?

Comment: Guess you want `amount = int(input())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of Python you're using.

### Python 3

You can simply pass the result of input (a string) to int (a function which turns a string into an integer).

```py
   amount = int(input("Enter a number"))
```

### Python 2

The python2 equivalent (to the `input` function from python3) is `raw_input`

```py
   amount = int(raw_input("Enter a number"))
```

Additionally it might be helpful to make your own `parse_input` function:

```py
def parse_input(parser, prompt='', defaultValue=None):
    try:
        return parser(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        return defaultValue
```

*replace `input` with `raw_input` for python2*

Typical usage:

```py
   amount = parse_input(int, "Enter a number", 0)
```